# ASP.Net MVC ViewBag is not working on functions which are called by AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have implemented a function to delete a record from a DB table. if there is an error, I want to pass it in ViewBag. But the ViewBag value is not passed to the View.

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteRecord(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)))
            {
                driver_tab driver = db.driver_tab.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Name == name);
                db.driver_tab.Remove(driver);
                db.SaveChanges();
                ViewBag.Msg = "1";
                MessageBox.Show(ViewBag.Msg);
                return View("Main");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Msg = "2";
                return View("Main");
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Msg = ex.Message.ToString();
            return View("Main");
        }
        catch (Exception ex2)
        {
            ViewBag.Msg = ex2.Message;
            return View("Main");
        }
    }
```

Ajax function in View

```
function DeleteSelectedRecord() {
    var SelectedName = $("#lstItems").val()
    $.ajax({
        url: 'DeleteRecord',
        method: "POST",
        data: { name: SelectedName }
    }).done(function () {
        $("#lstItems").empty();
        Search();
        GetCount();
        $('#modalDeleted').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function () { $('#modalDeleted').modal('hide'); }, 2000);
    });
}
```

I use this `ViewBag.Msg` in the view Like this `<h2>@ViewBag.Msg`
But it is not working.
What is the problem in my code.

If there any error occurred in the controller after executing the delete function, I want to pass that message to the view and display it. How to accomplish that..?

Comment: Could you please remove MessageBox.Show(ViewBag.Msg);
statement and try?

Answer (score 1):

You're AJAX is not using the response from `DeleteRecord`. This is what contains the rendered view HTML, including the ViewBag data.

You need to update your JavaScript to use the response, looking at your code I believe this needs to populate the modal your displaying:

Something like:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'DeleteRecord',
  method: "POST",
  data: { name: SelectedName }
}).done(function (data) {
  // Do something with response data, for example:
  $('#modalDeleted').html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an ajax POST, and you cant do a redirection/view change from server side using ajax. In your case, if you check the result in ajax success callback, ie, `done(function(data){....});, you should be getting what is returned from your Action method, here that would be your rendered html of Main view.

If the idea is to get a response back from delete Action, then return `Json result` instead of returning `View result`:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteRecord(string name)
{
  .....
  return Json(new {message = "your message based on business rule" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

and in javascript

```
function DeleteSelectedRecord() {
    var SelectedName = $("#lstItems").val()
    $.ajax({
        url: 'DeleteRecord',
        method: "POST",
        data: { name: SelectedName }
    }).done(function (result) {

       //append this message to any container of your view
        var message = result.message;

        $("#lstItems").empty();
        Search();
        GetCount();
        $('#modalDeleted').modal('show');
        setTimeout(function () { $('#modalDeleted').modal('hide'); }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting to another action you should use `TempData` like this:

```
catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
    TempData["error"] = ex.Message.ToString();
    return View("Main");
}
```

And in your view:

```
<h2>@Html.Display(TempData["error"])</h2
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are returning the view from different action i.e. redirecting from DeleteRecord action method to Main action method, if this is the case then you need to use TempData instead of ViewBag.